# GCF function crashes iOS with error: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code =2, address=0xbf7fffdc)

Tags: ios

My iOS app crashes when it tries to find the GCF sometimes. It doesn't happen all the time. Only sometimes.

Here is the GCF function:

```
+(NSNumber *)getGCFOf: (NSNumber *)frstNumber and: (NSNumber *)scndNumber {
    float t, r;

    //Convert input to floats
    float frstNumberFloat = frstNumber.floatValue;  //EXC_BAD_ACESS(code=2 address=0xbf7fffdc)
    float scndNumberFloat = scndNumber.floatValue;

    if (frstNumberFloat < scndNumberFloat){
        t = frstNumberFloat;
        frstNumberFloat = scndNumberFloat;
        scndNumberFloat = t;
    }

    r = fmodf(frstNumberFloat, scndNumberFloat);

    if (r == 0) {
        NSNumber *scndNumberNS = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:scndNumberFloat];
        return scndNumberNS;
    }
    else {
        NSNumber *inputOne = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: scndNumberFloat];
        NSNumber *inputTwo = [NSNumber numberWithFloat: r];
        return [Fractions getGCFOf: inputOne and: inputTwo];
    }
 }
```

Comment: Could you show the arguments you are passing to your function when crashing?

Comment: I think it has to be [frstNumber floatValue]...

Comment: -60,143 and 2987. Just for example. those aren't the only values that cause a crash

Comment: I mean, show the line where you call your function.

Answer (score 0):

This may be useful to look for the error:

EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 means that the pointer is corrupt because:

a) Have never been initialized.

b) Have been written over.

c) Could be part of an object that was casted incorrectly.